# How to install deployable app properly?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, setuptools, python-wheel

I want to deploy my python app, so planned to pack it as native .deb containing virtualenv on CI server and then distribute to servers. wheel_cache cant be used when using `setup.py` with `install_requires`. Moving all deps to `requirements.txt` and installing via pip makes `console_scripts` section from `setup.py` no longer available. So how to install deployable app properly? Via `pip install -r requirements.txt` (wheel cache speedup available) and then run e.g `/path/to/venv/bin/python -m mypackage` or maybe leave `setup.py` in addition to `requirements.txt` (with blank `install_requires`)?

Comment: Looks like I've found the answer in this [article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-package-dependency-blues)

Comment: If it's an app you definitely want `requirements.txt`http://blog.ziade.org/2013/04/13/declaring-dependencies-in-python/